# Failed to apply plugin 'com.gradle.build-scan'

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, build.gradle

**here is my build.gradle file**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os



buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
        classpath "com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.11"
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}


apply plugin: "com.gradle.build-scan"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'war' // for build excludes


sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            exclude 'Outputs/**'
        }
    }
}

//jar.enabled = false
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
mainClassName = "Main"

repositories{
    //maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    zip64 = true
}

ext {

    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_UNIX)) {
        os = 'linux'
    }
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_MAC)) {
        os = 'macosx'
    }
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        os = 'windows'
    }
    arch = System.getProperty("os.arch")

    if(arch == 'amd64'){
        arch = 'x86_64'
    }
    opencvBinaryClassifer = os+'-'+arch

}

dependencies {

    // Local libraries
    compile fileTree('lib')

    // General
    compile group: 'colt', name: 'colt', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.3-jre'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'

    // Tesseract - ocr
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'tesseract', version: '3.04.01-1.3'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'tesseract', version: '3.04.01-1.3', classifier: opencvBinaryClassifer
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.73-1.3', classifier: opencvBinaryClassifer
    compile group: 'org.languagetool', name: 'language-en', version: '3.8'

    // Testing
    testCompile group: 'org.loadui', name: 'testFx', version: '3.1.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.testfx', name: 'testfx-core', version: '4.0.8-alpha'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

jfx{
    verbose = true
    appName = "VideoText Extractor"
    mainClass = 'Main'
    vendor = 'Nikiforos Archakis'
    //bundler = 'windows.app'
//    bundleArguments = [
//            'runtime': 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144\\jre'
//    ]
}
```

am trying to run this application and getting error

1. i tried changing the gradle to version 11 in settinng.
2. tried uncomment this *apply plugin: "com.gradle.build-scan"*

- [**This is the error am getting***your text*]An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '3.15.1']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.gradle.build-scan'.
> The build scan plugin is not compatible with this version of Gradle.

**am trying to run a old java applicaion but unable to run it. he apllication is quite old.
Please assist.**

Comment: [Documentation on the build-scan plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.gradle.build-scan), and [user manual](https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/).  From the user manual, setting this plugin up to work correctly looks complicated and is out of my area of expertise.